# Java: Convert a hexadecimal encoded String to a hexadecimal byte

Tags: java, string, hex, byte

An Item-ID in hexadecimal and the amount in decimal has to be entered in two JTextFields.

Now I have to convert the Item ID hexadecimal encoded in a String to a byte hexadecimal.

```
String str = itemIdField.getText(); // Would be, for example, "5e"
byte b = // Should be 0x5e then.
```

So if str = "5e", b = 0x5e

if str = "6b" b = 0x6b and so on.

Does anybody now, what the code to convert that would be then?
Google doesn't know, it thinks, I want to convert the text to a byte[]

Thank you, Richie

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Byte.parseByte(str, 16)`, that will return the byte value represented by the hexadecimal value in `str`.

Comment: Thank you :) I would give U +1 but I haven't got enough reputation